# Node express multiple queries in one route that depend on each other

Tags: node.js, express

I am just about getting familiar with node and express and programming in general, but this is a more complex issue I am trying to solve. Please if you can provide with some best practice in this kind of scenario.

I am trying to run two queries to my database where the first one is dependent on the result of the first. Q1. Return a list of ids. Q2. Return id and coord for each of the ids. I want to respond with a json object that look something like this

```
[
  { id: 451, coords: 'POINT(12.5574 43.8351)' },
  { id: 56, coords: 'POINT(13.5574 44.8351)' }
]
```

Currently I cannot get it to work, I know there is probably several issues with my example code, but I have pretty much got stuck. Maybe I am overthinking this and make it harder than it is, or bad practice in general. 
How can I run multiple queries where the second use the output from the first one and then build the correct object to respond with. Any pointers would be much appreciated.

```
router.get('/asset/:id', (req, res) => {
  let latLngOfAssets = []
  // get associated assets
  function getConnectionsById() {
    queries.getConnectionsById(req.params.id)  // return list of objects
    .then(data => {
      if (data) {
        data.forEach(function(element) {
          getLatLngofAsset(element.til_poi_id)  // for each id in list call function to get coordinate
        });
      } else {
        throw new Error('No data returned');
      }
      console.log(latLngOfAssets) // What I want to respond with res.json(latlngofassets)
    })
  }

  function getLatLngofAsset(id) {
    queries.getPoilatlng(id)  // Return geometry as text for asset with id
    .then(data =>{
      let newassetobj = {}
      if (data) {
        newassetobj["id"] = data.rows[0].id
        newassetobj["coords"] = data.rows[0].st_astext
        //console.log(newassetobj)  // structure of each object { id: 451, coords: 'POINT(12.5574 43.8351)' }
        latLngOfAssets.push(newassetobj) // making list of objects i want to respond with
      } else {
        throw new Error('Did not get any poi');
      }
    })    
  }

  getConnectionsById()

  .catch(err => { // {message: "Cannot read property 'then' of undefined", error: {…}}
    console.error('Something went wrong', err);
  });
});
```

Comment: This is callback hell getting worse by defining nested functions and choosing function name same as of member function name

Comment: Use ``aggregate`` and ``$lookup`` to write cleaner queries

Comment: Thanks I will look into more of the details of what you are suggesting

Answer (score 1):

You've done a good job separating out the two distinct sections of your code into separate functions - what you're missing is the ability to tie them together. This portion of your code is not doing what I think you are trying to accomplish:

```
data.forEach(function(element) {
  getLatLngofAsset(element.til_poi_id)
});
```

Because `getLatLngofAsset()` is Promise-based* you need to use it like a Promise. You first need to make `getLatLngofAsset` return the Promise chain it creates. Then, it can be `await`-ed inside `getConnectionsById` using an `async` function:

```
 function getConnectionsById() {
    queries.getConnectionsById(req.params.id)
    .then(data => {
      if (data) {
        data.forEach(async function(element) { // <-- note the async keyword here
          await getLatLngofAsset(element.til_poi_id)
        });
      } else {
        throw new Error('No data returned');
      }
      console.log(latLngOfAssets) // What I want to respond with res.json(latlngofassets)
    })
  }
```

This is a start - there are a couple more things we can tackle once you understand the relationship between the functions you have declared and the Promises they create & return.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, not sure if I follow completely. The getLatLngofAsset() is calling the query in its body which is a promise (given from using knex js). It seem to be building the newassetobj for each id correctly. But it is for some reason not pushing it to the latLngOfAssets list, it is empty when I log it. I would however not be surprised if there is something i dont see.
I am not sure where I in the code should return the response with res.json(data)
I did try and just add the "await" as in your reply, but it gives me "SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"